# RequestParams params.put method doesn't receive integer

Tags: java, android, rest

I'm using Rest service to get a list of States of a Country (countryid) from database. The service runs well in Tomcat but it doesn't run in Android. Below is the code to invoke the Rest service. The params.put("countryid",countryID) method doesn't receive integer. Could you please help me over come this issue?

```
public void getDataForStateSpinner(){
    //new StateSpinnerAsync().execute();
    System.out.println("getDataForStateSpinner(), spnCountry adapter: " + spnCountry);
    System.out.println("spnCountry.getSelectedItem(): " + spnCountry.getSelectedItem());
    if (spnCountry.getSelectedItem()!=null){
        System.out.println("getDataForStateSpinner(), spnCountry adapter isn't empty");
        final Country country = (Country) spnCountry.getSelectedItem();
        int countryID = country.getCountryID();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        if (countryID>=0){
            params.put("countryid", countryID);
            invokeWS_State(params);
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(mParent.get(), "Can not get CountryID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } 
}

    public void invokeWS_State(RequestParams params){
    System.out.println("Inside invokeWS_State");
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    System.out.println("Inside invokeWS_State, client: " + client);
    System.out.println("Inside invokeWS_State onSuccess, params: " + params);
    client.get(stateURL, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String respond){
            try{
                System.out.println("Inside invokeWS_State onSuccess, stateURL: " + stateURL);

                System.out.println("Inside invokeWS_State onSuccess, respond:" + respond);
                JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(respond);
                //JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArr.getJSONObject(0);
                System.out.println("Inside invokeWS_State onSuccess jsonArr:" + jsonArr);
                String stateList = jsonArr.toString();
                System.out.println("Inside invokeWS_State onSuccess stateList:" + stateList);
                states = (ArrayList<State>) fromJasonToJava_State(stateList);
                for (State state : states) {
                    System.out.println("State id: " + state.getStateID() + " name: " + state.getStateName());
                }

                spnStateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<State>(mParent.get(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, states);
                spnStateAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spnState.setAdapter(spnStateAdapter);

            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content){
            String resultString = null;
            if (statusCode == 404){
                resultString = "Requested resource not found";
                Toast.makeText(mParent.get(), resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (statusCode == 500) {
                resultString = "Something went wrong at server end!";
                Toast.makeText(mParent.get(), resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                resultString = "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]";
                Toast.makeText(mParent.get(), resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

And below is the Rest service which runs well in Tomcat:

```
@Path("/State")
public class StatesResource {
@GET
@Path("/GetStates")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
//http://localhost:8080/com.fms.FMSRestfulWS/State/GetStates?countryid=1
public String getStates(@DefaultValue("1") @QueryParam("countryid") int countryID){
    String states = null;
    try{
        ArrayList<State> feedData = null;
        StateLoading stateLoading = new StateLoading();
        feedData = stateLoading.getAllStatesForCountry(countryID);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        states = gson.toJson(feedData);
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("System Error " + e);
    }

    return states;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do only one change, it will work perfect.

```
 params.put("countryid", ""+countryID);
```

Comment: I suppose you added "" to make countryID a string, didn't you? But countryid in the service is an integer.

Comment: yeah you are right actually getParams() method do not accept integer, so to make it string use double quotes with integer.

Comment: I guess so but it is ridiculous that it doesn't accept integer? So does it mean that I have to change the service on the way to String?

Comment: no man you need not change in services, in my projects i have also used so many integers and at last  i use double quotes with integer. It means value will be same nothing will be happen with your integer. May be your problem is different, if it was the problem with integer, then it would definitely work with my answer

Comment: Hey, if you want to add "" when you invoke the service, it means the service parameter needs to be String, am I correct?

Comment: I changed the service to this

Comment: Changed the parameter in the service to String and used and temp variable int temp = Integer.parseInt(countryID); to convert String to Integer before transmiting the variable to feedData = stateLoading.getAllStatesForCountry(temp); to get the list of States corresponding to the countryID. It works. But I still feel very uncomfortable to change the service.